# Membership for list of arrays: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() error problem

Tags: python, valueerror

```
Q = [np.array([0, 1]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([2, 3]), np.array([3, 4])]
for q in Q:
    print(q in Q)
```

Running the code above, it gives me the result 'True' at the first iteration, while ValueError comes out afterwards.

> True

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I have no idea why it starts to go wrong at second iteration. Anybody can help me plz..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you can't use `in` to test for numpy arrays in a Python list. It will only ever work for the first element, because of an optimisation in the way Python tests for equality.

What's happening is that the implementation for `list.__contains__` (which `in` defers to), is using a short-cut to find a match faster, by first *checking for identity*. Most people using Python know this as the [`is` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not). This is faster than `==` equality checks because all `is` has to do is see if the pointers of both objects are the same value, it is worth checking for *first*. An identity test works the same for any Python object, including numpy arrays.

The implementation essentially would look like this if it was written in Python:

```
def __contains__(self, needle):
    for elem in self:
        if needle is elem or needle == elem:
            return True
    return False
```

What happens for your list of numpy arrays then is this:

- `for q in Q`, step 1: `q = Q[0]`

  - `q in Q` is then the same as `Q.__contains__(Q[0])`

    - `Q[0] is self[0]` => `True`!
- `for q in Q`, step 2: `q = Q[1]`

  - `q in Q` is then the same as `Q.__contains__(Q[1])`

    - `Q[1] is self[0]` => `False` :-(
    - `Q[1] == self[0]` => `array([False, False])`, because Numpy arrays use [*broadcasting* to compare each element in both arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

The `array([False, False])` result is *not a boolean*, but `if` wants a boolean result, so it is passed to (C equivalent of) the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool). `bool(array([False, False]))` produces the error you see.

Or, done manually:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Q = [np.array([0, 1]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([2, 3]), np.array([3, 4])]
>>> Q[0] is Q[0]
True
>>> Q[1] is Q[0]
False
>>> Q[1] == Q[0]
array([False, False])
>>> bool(Q[1] == Q[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You'll have to use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`numpy.array_equal()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) to create a version of `list.__contains__` that doesn't use (normal) `==` equality checks:

```
def list_contains_array(lst, arr):
    return any(np.array_equal(arr, elem) for elem in lst)
```

and you can then use that to get `True` for your loop:

```
>>> for q in Q:
...     print(list_contains_array(Q, q))
...
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 3):

When you compare two Python lists for equality, you get a single `True` or `False` result:

```py
>>> [0, 1] == [0, 1]
True
>>> [0, 1] == [1, 2]
False
```

But when you compare `numpy` arrays for equality, the result is another `numpy` array where each element *i* is the result of comparing the *i*th element of the first array with the *i*th element of the second array:

```py
>>> np.array([0, 1]) == np.array([0, 1])
array([ True,  True])
>>> np.array([0, 1]) == np.array([1, 2])
array([False, False])
```

When you execute `q in Q`, it will test `q` for `is` with each element of `Q`  and if they are not the same elements it will then do a comparison for equality. This is repeated until if finds an "equal" match (identity or compares equal), in which case it will return `True`, else return `False` if it finds no "equal" match.

When `q` is the first element of `Q` as is the case the first time through the loop, it compares itself first with the first element of `Q` and finds the `is` condition exists and thus returns `True`:

```py
>>> True if Q[0] is Q[0] or Q[0] == Q[0] else False
True
```

But the second time through the loop, `q` is the second element of `Q` and when it is compared with the first element of `q`, since the `is` condition is not met, it tries to do an equality comparison:

```py
>>> True if Q[1] is Q[0] or Q[1] == Q[0] else False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```